# Registers an unload listener & Page prevented back/forward cache restoration 1 failure reason

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, dnn9

Running a Google Lighthouse report on any of my DNN sites and I am getting the following errors;

```
Page prevented back/forward cache restoration 1 failure reason

Registers an unload listener

(ScriptResource.axd:5)
```

---

Is there an expert out there who can advise on how to resolve / or fix this problem for me?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://web.dev/articles/bfcache#never_use_the_unload_event) will be of use to you.